# Jboss Fuse, error: No feature named 'commons-dbcp2' with version '0.0.0' available

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

When I try to install my package

```
mvn:br.com.mycompany/integration/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I receive the follow error:

```
Unable to start bundle mvn:br.com.dbitech/animus/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Unresolved constraint in bundle Integration [359]: Unable to resolve 359.0: missing requirement [359.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.commons.dbcp2)(version>=2.1.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
```

And when I try to install the dbcp2 feature, the follow error ocurs:

```
Error executing command: No feature named 'commons-dbcp2' with version '0.0.0' available
```

How I install an feature that don't is in the fuse index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how install a dependency:

In this case I need to Wrap the bundle and your dependencies:

```
osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-pool2/2.4.2
osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-dbcp2/2.1.1
```